# Sending Fax SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008-r2

I m try to send a fax through SQl server 2008.

```
EXECUTE master.sys.xp_sendmail 
@recipients='[FAX:XXXXXXX]', 
@message=' <Message details>’, @subject=’<subject> ' 
EXECUTE master..xp_stopmail
```

Unfortunately it giving me the error as below

```
Msg 17938, Level 16, State 0, Line 0
SQL Mail does not work with the 64-bit version of SQL Server
Msg 17938, Level 16, State 0, Line 0
SQL Mail does not work with the 64-bit version of SQL Server
```

I get google what can be the possible turnaround, but there nothing related to SQL Server 2008.

Any inputs would be appreciated.

Thanks !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

xp_sendmail is obsolete and does not work 64-bit machines.  Instead, use [Database Mail](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175887%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

I would also consider if the database is the correct source of sending emails and/or faxes.  Is this something better handled elsewhere-- like in a web service or client application?

Comment: The `[FAX:...]` syntax is an MAPI/Outlook option. Database Mail uses directly SMTP. It is possible, at least in theory, to send a fax using SMTP (and thus using Database Mail) but it requires a [SMTP-Fax gateway](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fax_server). I have never tested such a gateway with Database Mail. Besides, who still uses Fax in 2012, anyway?

Comment: And it works? Well, that's fantastic! However I still suggest this is better handled outside the database. And @Remus I understand that it can *possibly* be done with other scaffolding, my point was you can't just throw a fax recipient at database mail and expect it to work out of the box.

Answer (score 2):

Send your fax from an external program (e.g. C#). Much better equipped to do this than SQL Server will ever be, especially using xp_sendmail which, as you might have gathered from the error message, is not functional on 64-bit and SQL Mail has been [deprecated for ages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143729%28SQL.100%29.aspx) anyway.